# Bash: How to replace ending ' with variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have been trying to learn sed; but I am not very good at it yet.
I am trying to edit a file in bash.
The contents of the file are something similar to:
`__version__='1.2.3'` and I want the output to be `__version__="1.2.3.${some_var}'`

I tried doing a sed to replace the last ' with the variable but I have had no luck.
Currently I have 
`export some_var=1`
I tried doing:
`export version="$(cat airmap/skynet/version.py)"
export version="${version: : -1}"
echo "$(cat file.txt).$dateSeconds'" > file.txt`

So then I tried to do sed
`sed -i "s/\'/.${some_var}"` but that was not happy.

Any advice would be super helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
some_var="42"
sed "s/'$/.${some_var}'/" file
```

Output:

```
__version__='1.2.3.42'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "__version__='1.2.3'"  | sed 's/\'$/${some_var}\'/'
__version__='1.2.3${some_var}'
```

using backslash escape single quote

Comment: You [cannot embed an escaped single quote within single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes). You'll have to do `sed 's/'\''$/${somevar}'\''/'` or `sed "s/'\$/\${some_var}'/"`